# Trying to generate a list of data to plot a graph with error bars. Need help creating the looping function

Tags: plotting, graphics, list-manipulation

This is the sets of data I want to put into a form which will allow me to plot error bars from the min and max data.

```
avg = {{10, 0.662}, {20, 0.96}, {30, 0.916}, {40, 0.787}, {50,0.621}, {60, 0.453}}
min = {{0.55`}, {0.91`}, {0.85`}, {0.72`}, {0.58`}, {0.42`}}
max = {{0.76`}, {1.02`}, {0.99`}, {0.85`}, {0.68`}, {0.51`}}
```

This following code worked with n=1, creating one point on the graph. How do I make it loop to n=Length[avg] to plot all the points?

```
errmin = min[[n]] - avg[[n, 2]]
errmax = max[[n]] - avg[[n, 2]]
err = Flatten[{errmin, errmax}]
data = {{avg[[n]], ErrorBar[err]}}

ylabel = "Voltage (V \[PlusMinus] 0.05)"
xlabel = "Blade Angle (\[Degree] \[PlusMinus] 3)"
title = "Preliminary - Altering Blade Angle"
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
ErrorListPlot[data, Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
 Mesh -> Full, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 AxesLabel -> {xlabel, ylabel}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Dotted, PlotLabel -> Style[title, Bold], 
 LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Helvetica")]
```

I should point out I'm new to Mathematica today so please don't be too technical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html). Specifically, I would generate your data using this code

```
data = MapThread[
        {#1, ErrorBar[{#2[[1]] - #1[[2]], #3[[1]] - #1[[2]]}]} &, 
        {avg, min, max}
]
```

which when input into your `ErrorListPlot` you get

[image]

Note, I added the option `PlotRange -> All` as it was getting cut off.

---

Now to explain the code. `MapThread` pulls a single element out of each list passed to it (the second parameter), and applies a function to them (the first parameter). In this case, the function is

```
{#1, ErrorBar[{#2[[1]] - #1[[2]], #3[[1]] - #1[[2]]}]} &
```

Here the [`#n`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html) terms (called Slots) refer to the parameters passed by number, so `#1` is from `avg`, etc. The `&` at the end tells *Mathematica* that it is a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).

Comment: Ah that's brilliant, thank you!

Comment: @TheoWindebank you're welcome. Don't forget to vote for good answers, and to accept the one that is the most helpful.

Comment: @TheoWindebank you should also look closely at [s0rce's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13752/52) as it talks a bit about vector operations which will simplify your life.

Comment: Say now I have multiple sets of data, can I use a similar method to make multiple graphs without just copying the code over and over?

Comment: @TheoWindebank I'm not sure what you mean. You can turn it into a function, or I'd do this: `ErrorListPlot[MapThread[..., #], ...]& /@ {{avg, min, max}, ...}` where the ellipses are filled in as appropriate.

Comment: I made a new post to try and make it clearer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13759/use-single-listplot-for-multiple-sets-of-data-on-seperate-graphs.

Answer (score 5):

```
avg = {{10, 0.662}, {20, 0.96}, {30, 0.916}, {40, 0.787}, {50, 
   0.621}, {60, 0.453}}
min = {{0.55`}, {0.91`}, {0.85`}, {0.72`}, {0.58`}, {0.42`}}
max = {{0.76`}, {1.02`}, {0.99`}, {0.85`}, {0.68`}, {0.51`}}
```

You can perform subtraction on the whole list

```
errmin = min[[All, 1]] - avg[[All, 2]];
errmax = max[[All, 1]] - avg[[All, 2]];
```

combine the errmin and errmax

```
error = Transpose[{errmin, errmax}];
```

combine data and error

```
dataerror = MapThread[{#1, ErrorBar[#2]} &, {avg, error}];
```

now plot it all

```
ErrorListPlot[dataerror, 
 Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 2, Mesh -> Full, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {xlabel, ylabel}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Dotted, 
 PlotLabel -> Style[title, Bold], 
 LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Helvetica")]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]