# Use single ListPlot for multiple sets of data (on separate graphs)

Tags: plotting, graphics, list-manipulation

This is the code I have working for a single set of data. Is there a way I can structure this to have multiple sets of data?

```
title = "Preliminary - Altering Blade Angle";
ylabel = "Voltage (V ± 0.05)";
xlabel = "Blade Angle (° ± 3)";
avg = {{10, 0.662}, {20, 0.96}, {30, 0.916}, {40, 0.787}, {50, 
    0.621}, {60, 0.453}};
min = {{0.55`}, {0.91`}, {0.85`}, {0.72`}, {0.58`}, {0.42`}};
max = {{0.76`}, {1.02`}, {0.99`}, {0.85`}, {0.68`}, {0.51`}};

data = MapThread[{#1, 
     ErrorBar[{#2[[1]] - #1[[2]], #3[[1]] - #1[[2]]}]} &, {avg, min, 
    max}];

Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
ErrorListPlot[data, Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
 Mesh -> Full, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 AxesLabel -> {xlabel, ylabel}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Dotted, PlotLabel -> Style[title, Bold], 
 LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Helvetica"), PlotRange -> All, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

Maybe I could do something like this:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
title = {{"Preliminary - Altering Blade Angle"}, {"experiment 2"}};
ylabel = {{"Voltage (V ± 0.05)"}, {"ylabel 2"}};
xlabel = {{"Blade Angle (° ± 3)"}, {"xlabel 2"}};
avg = {
   {{10, 0.662}, {20, 0.96}, {30, 0.916}, {40, 0.787}, {50, 
     0.621}, {60, 0.453}},

   {{5, 0}, {10, 0.564`}, {15, 0.795`}, {20, 0.903`}, {25, 
     0.933`}, {30, 0.908`}, {35, 0.844}}
   };
min = {
   {{0.55`}, {0.91`}, {0.85`}, {0.72`}, {0.58`}, {0.42`}},
   {{0}, {0.52`}, {0.74`}, {0.78`}, {0.8`}, {0.84`}, {0.78}}
   };
max = {{{0.76`}, {1.02`}, {0.99`}, {0.85`}, {0.68`}, {0.51`}},
   {{0}, {0.6`}, {0.84`}, {0.98`}, {1.06`}, {0.97`}, {0.92}}
   };
```

for the first part? I'm not sure how to structure the second part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps just

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
data[i_] := MapThread[{#1, ErrorBar[{#2[[1]] - #1[[2]], #3[[1]] - #1[[2]]}]} &, 
                    {avg[[i]], min[[i]], max[[i]]}];

Framed@Column[
  ErrorListPlot[data@#, Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
     Mesh -> Full, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
     AxesLabel -> {xlabel[[#,1]], ylabel[[#,1]]}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
     GridLinesStyle -> Dotted, PlotLabel -> Style[title[[#,1]], Bold], 
     LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Helvetica"), PlotRange -> All, 
     ImageSize -> 600] & /@ Range@Length@avg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it threw up a lot of errors http://cl.ly/image/2L2C2t1l300k

Comment: @TheoWindebank Works Ok. here. Perhaps a version problem. Before going deeper, shut down mathematica and run it in a fresh session.

Comment: Well that's strange, it appears to work after restarting it and using a new notepad. Thanks for your help. What do you think could have caused that to happen?

Comment: @TheoWindebank Typically, some previous definition of `data`

Comment: Oh hang on, I've noticed a problem. I want the graphs to have different titles and labels but each graph has both of them http://cl.ly/image/3l172q2B1E1l

Comment: @TheoWindebank Test it now.

Comment: Flawless, thank you very much.